# inserting multiple values into SQL with %

Tags: sqlite, python

This works:

```
cursor = conn.execute("""Select FAMILY,F_NAME from birthday where B_MONTH = '%s' """ % (currentMonth))
```

I cannot seem to expand it to work using an AND clause to also include day, I get a syntax error:

```
cursor = conn.execute("""Select FAMILY,F_NAME from birthday where B_MONTH = '%s' AND B_DAY = '%s' """ % (currentMonth),%(currentDay))
```

Answer (score 3):

The `%` operator takes a string on its left side, and a list of values on its right side:

```
execute("SELECT ... WHERE B_MONTH = '%s' AND B_DAY = '%s'" % (currentMonth, currentDay))
```

Please note that using `%` introduces the risk of SQL injections when used with strings, so you should always use SQL parameters instead:

```
execute("SELECT ... WHERE B_MONTH = ? AND B_DAY = ?", (currentMonth, currentDay))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not transfer current month/day as parameters from python, SQLite can do it using its own functions.

```
cursor = conn.execute("""SELECT family,f_name 
                         FROM birthday 
                         WHERE b_month = STRFTIME('%m','now') 
                           AND b_day = STRFTIME('%d','now')""")
```